# Show that $\exists g$ such that $f(x+y)=f(x)+yf'(x)+yg(x,y)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f\in \mathcal C^1([0,1],\mathbb R)$. Show that $\exists g\in\mathcal C^0(\mathbb R^2,\mathbb R)$ such that $\forall(x,t)\in\mathbb R^2, f(x+y)=f(x)+yf'(x)+yg(x,y)$.

We can start off by noticing that :

$\begin{eqnarray}f(x+y)=f(x)+f(x+y)-f(x)=f(x)+y\left[\frac{f(x+ty)}{y}\right]^1_0\end{eqnarray}=f(x)+y\displaystyle\int_0^1f'(x+ty)dt$

Therefore, by letting $g(x,y)=\displaystyle\int_0^1f'(x+ty)dt-f'(x)$ we get the desired equality. All I have left to show is that the integral is continuous with respect to $(x,y)$ which should be the case because you're integrating a continuous function but I don't really see how to prove it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Just define $g(x,y)$ as $\frac {f(x+y)-f(x)} y-f'(x)$ if $y \neq 0$ and $0$ if $y=0$. It is quite easy to see that $g$ is continuous using MVT and continuity of $f'$.